# Does the community bot downvote?

Tags: support, voting, community-user

I got an [auto comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/443771/trigger-automatic-export-to-csv-while-saving-the-numbers-sheet/443786#comment641390_443786) to improve my answer, which is fine.

But I'm curious if the bot is the one that downvoted me or if other people downvoted me.

Does the bot vote?

Comment: Well, I can understand why somebody downvotes „ Specifically i have nothing but it seems like you might be able to use Automator to do something like that. You'd probably have to look into whatever communities there are for automator to see if we can get it triggered on save.“ as it basically repeats the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, the bot does not vote. But,

- it does own votes by users which are later deleted, in the rare case that their votes are preserved
- it downvotes [posts flagged as Very Low Quality when that flag is marked helpful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230635/295232)
- it downvotes [posts flagged as spam or rude/abusive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=profile)

However, that's not the case here. It must have been a regular user that downvoted your post.